# Why is cargo build not showing compilation errors with incompatible dependencies?

Tags: rust, dependencies, traits, rust-cargo

*Since this issue involves multiple dependencies and I'm not sure in which direction to look for reproducing it, I hope it is fine to ask it based on a specific example. The more general pattern behind this question is: There is a dependency chain `user => libExtension => libBase` and `libExtension` and `libBase` are incompatible.*

In the [geo-booleanop](https://github.com/21re/rust-geo-booleanop) project, we run into an interesting [issue](https://github.com/21re/rust-geo-booleanop/issues/22) that we cannot fully understand. It involves the interplay of the following packages:

- [geo-types](https://crates.io/crates/geo-types) *(`libBase`)*: A core library that provides basic types like lines, rects, polygons, etc.
- [geo-booleanop](https://github.com/21re/rust-geo-booleanop) *(`libExtension`)*: A library building on top of geo-types, extending it with one new functionality: A new trait `BooleanOp` that has functions like intersection/union/... and is implemented for the polygon type from geo-types.
- Any user package that pulls together geo-types and geo-booleanop with the intention of using the `BooleanOp` trait for polygons.

The package geo-types recently had a breaking change going from version 0.4 to 0.5, e.g., it changed some of the fields of its `Rect` type from pub fields to getters.

The geo-booleanop package is not yet adopted to this change, i.e., it still makes explicit use of these pub fields. Currently, the `Cargo.toml` of geo-booleanop specifies `geo-types = "0.4"`, and an attempt to bump it to 0.5 and doing `cargo build` within geo-booleanop leads to compiler errors at the pub field accesses as expected.

Now the surprising thing: When creating a user package that combines the latest versions of geo-types and geo-booleanop, we see the following output from `cargo build` in the user package:

```
$ cargo build
[...]
   Compiling geo-booleanop v0.2.1
   Compiling geo-types v0.5.0
[...]

error[E0599]: no method named `union` found for type `geo_types::polygon::Polygon<{float}>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:21:23
   |
21 |     let union = poly1.union(&poly2);
   |                       ^^^^^ method not found in `geo_types::polygon::Polygon<{float}>`
```

That is surprising because:

- Compiling geo-booleanop v0.2.1 in combination with geo-types v0.5.0 should not be possible at all, because they are incompatible.
- The error about no method named `union` is confusing, because the user code does everything right to bring the `BooleanOp` trait into scope, which should provide exactly that method for polygons.
- Ironically the compiler also outputs a warning that the `BooleanOp` trait import is unused.

---

My questions are:

- Why is `cargo build` not showing compilation errors highlighting the incompatibility of the dependencies?
- If that is by design, is there anything we could do on geo-booleanop site to make such problems easier for our users to grasp? Currently they do everything right in terms of the written code to bring the trait into scope, and yet the compiler behaves as if the trait is missing -- whereas in reality it is a version mismatch. Can we enforce a more explicit error on library site?

---

Details in case they matter:

- The `BooleanOp` trait is generic in its underlying floating point type ([see implementation](https://github.com/21re/rust-geo-booleanop/blob/a8aa03e58786910c8eb6ddcb7d07861a29552961/lib/src/boolean/mod.rs#L29-L50)). Is this causing the problem, because generics do not get instantiated until client code uses it like in other programming languages?
- This is the reproducing client code: [main.rs](https://github.com/inclooder/rust-geo-test/blob/master/src/main.rs) and [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/inclooder/rust-geo-test/blob/master/Cargo.toml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize your scenario as follows:

- your Cargo.toml depends on `geo-booleanop` 0.2.1 and `geo-types` 0.5.0
- `geo-booleanop` 0.2.1 depends on `geo-types` 0.4.x

If you look at your Cargo.lock file, you would notice that there are two `[[package]]` entries for `geo-types`, one for `0.4.x` and one for `0.5.0`.

When two (transitive) dependency requirements of the same project are incompatible,
cargo actually attempts to compile *both* of them.
Cargo does not expose indirect dependencies to your crate,
so Cargo is building both versions separately as if they don't have the same crate name.
As long as you don't try to use `geo-types` with `geo-booleanop`,
they can actually work independently.

For clarity I call the two versions `geo_types_04` and `geo_types_05` respectively.
geo-booleanop works on a dependency called `geo_types_04`,
where `geo_types_04` is not exposed to your crate,
so you don't need to care if `geo_types_04` is used at all.

It only becomes a problem when `geo-booleanop` exposes a function that accepts/returns some type defined in `geo_types_04`.
Then you assume it is `geo_types_05`,
resulting in incompatibility.

Your error this time is actually one of the more readable ones.Sometimes you would get errors like `Expected geo_types::Line, got geo_types::Line` because the function accepting `geo_types_04::Line` is called with a `geo_types_05::Line`.

Comment: Hm, the whole purpose of `geo-booleanop` is to extend the functionality of a type in `geo-types`. It is helpful to know that internally there are two versions `geo-types`, but that seems to defeat the entire purpose of extending a core type with an addon trait. Is there really no way to make this issue more clear to users, especially since the confusing "missing trait" errors will come back with every future breaking change in `geo-types`? For instance, could `geo-booleanop`'s Cargo.toml specify that it wants the same version of `geo-types` later determined by users?

Comment: geo-booleanop only supports specific versions of geo-types. It doesn't support an arbitrary version specified by the user.

Comment: Is it recommended than to use `geo-types = "*"` in such addon libraries to make sure the addon trait can follow the base library arbitrarily? If a new major version of `geo-types` is released that is still compatible, users can move on to the new version immediately. If the new major version is incompatible, users would see the actual compilation errors, which are better to report as GitHub issues then the re-occurring "missing trait" issue. Are wildcard dependencies a thing for addon libraries that have the goal to always follow the base library and let the user determine the library version?

Comment: No, it is not recommended. New major versions are *not compatible* by definition. Lack of compile errors, although usually reliable, does not necessarily imply compatibility. In addition, if your current crate is a library, you are arbitrarily supporting any future versions, and users won't even know which version you were targetting.

Comment: Surely not the answer I was hoping for, since I still don't see how to prevent the issue from re-occurring with every major release. Accepting that there isn't a solution ;).

Comment: The best solution is to have `geo-booleanop` updated as soon as `geo-types` bumps the major version. This is usually the case if they are maintained by the same person. Otherwise you could also consider maintaining a fork of the outdated library.